# Is it possible to fetch Randomised MAC Address using 3rd part Android App?

Tags: android

Apps targeting API 30 can not get the Wifi MAC Address unless they have the special privilege like Device Owner or enhanced Work Profile.
https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids#mac-11-plus

API #29 introduced an API to get the randomized Wifi MAC address of the network, but that was also deprecated in API 29 with WifiConfiguration class.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiConfiguration#getRandomizedMacAddress()

I want to fetch either the Wifi MAC Address or the Randomized MAC address from the device using my app.
is there any solution for the same?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Android allows that because of privacy. Only System android apps can access that data.

Comment: Any thoughts for Randomised MAC addreess?

Comment: As i said Only System android apps can access that randomized bluetooth address. And TBH, you don't really need it.